# How do I get my JSON from SSMS? (An error occurred while parsing EntityName)

Tags: json, sql-server

SSMS fails to format my JSON due to illegal XML characters, as referenced in [this topic](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3e89dfb5-b2d7-45a5-b2f8-1e8527498118/error-for-json-path-fails-when-parsing-an-ampersand-amp?forum=sqltools).

My use case is trying to do some A-B testing using two environments in our workplace (Dev and Staging). Due to the sandbox nature of environments, Dev cannot talk to Staging, and vice versa. I've been utilizing JSON to pass the data back and forth, since the data structures are identical between environments.

Using "Save Results as...", as recommended in the topic I linked, causes illegal characters and line-breaks to show up in the file. I wrote a Python script (seen below) and it shows these three characters being written by SSMS:

"ï»¿"

SQL Server 2016 Code

```
select top 1000 
    '&' as test, 
    row_number() over (order by o.[object_id]) as test_id 
from 
    sys.all_objects o 
    cross join sys.all_columns c 
for 
    json path;
```

Python 3.6 Code

```
import os
import json

for file in filter(lambda f: f.endswith(".json"), os.listdir()):
    builder = list()

    with open(file, "r") as jsonFile:
        for line in jsonFile:
            builder.append("".join(line.split()))

    file_contents = "".join(builder)

    with open(file, "w") as jsonFile:
        json.dump(json.loads(file_contents[3:]), jsonFile)
```

I'm able to run the above code, and get what I need, but I'm wondering if anyone can explain 1) how to skip this intermediate step of exporting to a file and 2) why the file created has erroneous characters at the start of the stream?

Comment: Instead of File > Save Results As, have you tried running the query with the Results to File option? I would leave SSMS out of it, to be honest; just pull the data from Powershell or SQLCMD or C# and write it out however you like.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, the problem remains in a separate way, in that the column represented is "JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B" followed by a new line, then 256 hyphens, and the JSON text split into lines of 256 characters making up 14 lines in the sample query provided. It also adds a row count message at the bottom, which can be coded for, but still leaves me with a less than ideal solution.

Side note: Never expected to see your name pop up on a question of mine. I really enjoy a lot of your write-ups.

Comment: Sounds mostly like SSMS just isn't the right tool for this. You can fool the column name by putting the code inside a stored procedure and using `WITH RESULT SETS` but you'll still get the 256 dashes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can remove SSMS as a requirement, this is easy to do from bcp. The difficulty here is getting it all on one line. First I'll show it as a placeholder:

```
bcp "<query>" queryout c:\temp\json.csv -c -T -Sserver\instance
```

Here's the whole thing:

```
bcp "select top 1000  '&' as test, row_number() over (order by o.[object_id]) as test_id from  sys.all_objects o  cross join sys.all_columns c for     json path;" queryout c:\temp\json.csv -c -T -Sserver\instance
```

This provides JSON output with no column headers and no issues with the XML entities (but I don't know if the output is the perfect JSON you expect).

Comment: Thanks for the replies on the subject. While, as you mentioned, this doesn't give perfect JSON, it does at least answer as much of my question as is relevant within StackOverflow. This skips the need to "Save Results As..." and directly outputs the values into a file, that I can pass into my Python script for cleansing. It really seems like Microsoft needs to up their support for JSON to be at parity with the XML data type, methods, and serialization options.